# QWebView : Flash / Youtube videos not working

Tags: qt

I am currently working on a multitouch software, in which we used Qt Webkit to display web views ; we use mainly QML associated with CPP backend, but we had some issues with Quick 2.0 WebView.. (Essentially applying a rotation on it leads to clipping and position problems). So we had to use the CPP QWebView, which we paint in a QQuickPaintedItem.

Everything works quite great, but we can’t figure out how to display videos (for example Youtube video) ; basically we have no debug or error message, but the video stays black without the controls appearing and no sound. Sometimes it just crashes.

I tryed creating a new project from scratch and just put a webview, same issue. Maybe is it an architecture problem ?
We work with Debian Jessie, and I think the flash plugins that are used by Qt are the Mozilla alternatives.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check you have enabled plugins by setting the `QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled` attribute to `true`.

Enable the attribute with the following code:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

See the [`QWebSettings`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum) documentation for details.

**Edit**

The following example app (in Qt 4) works for me, although I have to reload the page for the test animation to show:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWebKit>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);

  QWebView view;
  view.show();
  view.load(QUrl("https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html"));

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Yep it's enabled, and I try deleting some files to see which version was used ; it is clearly mozilla alternatives, 'cause I have the Youtube message "flash not installed" if I delete it ;)

Comment: would it possible in qtjambi? @JérémyDutheil